# Vertical text alignment not working for some font sizes

Tags: javascript, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am making a window where the components need to scale according to the height of the window, as the user resizes it.
To this end, I have some JS to update the css style of the components whenever the window changes size.

For one of the components, I want the text inside it to be centered, but for some font sizes, the text is placed too high up:
[Bad vertical alignment example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfjH6.png)
I scaled up this example to make it more clear. There are 1px of space above the text, and 3px below.

I have tried

- setting lineHeight = height, and vertical align center
- setting display flex, align-items center, and wrapping the text in a child div/span.
- setting lineHeight = 1, and appropriate padding top/bottom (same values)

In all situations above, I also set height and font-size to a value that matches the current window height. I also tried avoiding fractional font sizes, by having the font size rounded to the nearest integer.

It all works in most situations, but there are always some window sizes where the alignment messes up. Particularly for smaller window sizes.

The html consists of a display flex div with button elements, each containing the text to be centered.

---

#### Edit 1:

I reproduced it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz7p2joy/6/

```
<div class="strip">
  <button>SBO</button>
  <button>PIN</button>
  <button>ISN</button>
</div>

.strip{
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #3F3F46;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button{
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0px 3.8452px;
    text-align: center;
    
    background-color: #007ACC;
    color: #F1F1F1;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #3F3F46;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

It is subtle, but there are 3 px of space below the text, and 1px above. This might depend a bit on the computer/monitor/browser it is run on. I have seen some worse examples on users' machines (Might be related to windows display scaling).

Comment: do you use <p> or  <div> for ther text parts? You could try display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; on the parent container. This should align the child contents centered no matter which viewport  size.

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained example of what you already have in the question please? As a general rule it should not be necessary to click through to off-site resources  to understand the question.